# Use another pipe after sanitize pipe

Tags: angular

I need to get 200 characters from data which I get from sanitized pipe.

Now my code looking like:

```
<div class="description mt-3" [innerHTML]="body | sanitizeHtml">
  </div>
```

Sanitize pipe`s code:

```
transform(content: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
```

So, I need to pass data which I get from first pipe (sanitized data) to another pipe, like so:

```
<div class="description mt-3" [innerHTML]="body | sanitizeHtml | getFirst20Ch">
  </div>
```

But when data come from sanitizeHtml its not have  **string** type and I cant get 20 characters after sanitazing from getFirst20Ch pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bypassSecurityTrustHtml` is not doing what you expect.

Create an element in memory only and add the HTML, then use the `textContent` or `innerText` getter to get the text content.

```ts
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><p><span>a</span>b</span><b>c</b><span>c</span></p></div>';
this.content = div.textContent;
```

and display it with

```ts
<div>{{content | getFirst20Ch}}</div>
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7topuv)

You can also implement this as pipe of course.

Comment: If i do this, then i will get first 20 characters with markup elements <h1></h2>

Comment: `sanitizeHtml` is probably not doing what you expect. All it does is applying a special marker for Angular to know it is safe to add the content to the DOM. It doesn't manipulate the content in any other way. Please explain what the expected behavior is.

Comment: i have data, which contains markup, like <h2>Data</h2>. And i need to remove markup and get first 3 character from 'Data' like 'Dat'

Comment: Thanks! You save my day =)

Comment: Glad to hear :)